# Adding Image in Google App Engine

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I have a html page in my Google app engine project. I have stored an image titled "image.jpg" under a folder titled "images" which is under the project folder.

I'm trying to load the image in my html code with this:

```
<img width=150 src="~/images/image.jpg">
```

However I get the following warning and the image is not displayed on the page:

> WARNING: No file found for: /~/images/image.jpg

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your app.yaml file you need a handler for images

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
```

and then `<img width=150 src="/images/image.jpg">`

provided that you are using python and not java or go

Comment: I did this "application: mscscsu
version: 1
runtime: java

handlers:
static_files:
  - include: /images/**.png" But I still get the same error

Comment: I've never coded in java before, but it looks like `application: mscscsu version: 1 runtime: java handlers: static_files: - include: /images/**.png` should be jpg rather than png, considering the img you're trying to call is a jpg.

Answer (score 1):

this works too:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))
static_files: \1
upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))
```

also is a good idea to add "alt" property inside img.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 handlers:
one for the main app
and one for the images directory:
`handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: login.app
- url: /(..(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (..(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))`

Writing the image handler above the second handler (url: /.*) seemed to get the images working : 

`handlers:
- url:/(.`*.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))
- url: /.*
  script: login.app

*Handler for the images is taken from @[kataku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751123/kataku)'s answer 
 Cheers !